# Equality checking: the value of another cell within the COUNTIF function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to determine if a row contains a cell with a certain value, using the IF function.

It's easy when I use a constant number; in my case, I use

```
=IF( COUNTIF(E16:J16,"=29")>0, "yes", "" )
```

to determine if R16 contains any cells with value 29.

Can I store 29 in another cell (say, `P16`) and check whether my row contains any cells with the same value as `P16`?

I've tried

```
=IF( COUNTIF(E16:J16,"=P16")>0, "yes", "" )
```

but this doesn't work (although the program doesn't complain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for the literal string "=P16" not the contents of of the cell `P16`.

Your formula should be:

```
=IF( COUNTIF(E16:J16,P16)>0, "yes", "" )
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `""` in addressing another cell...

```
=IF( COUNTIF(E16:J16,P16)>0, "yes", "" )
```

Comment: Damnit! I was too busy typing my answer in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51614213#51614213)!